# loading different m3u playlist and mp3 on click

Tags: javascript, media

I am trying to make an audio player for my website that plays album playlist(m3u) and Individual mp3's on click. They're are going to be several playlist and mp3's so I need the song to auto go to the next song. And I need option to go to NEXT or PREVIOUS song

I do believe that I have started writing the code for the playLast and playNext but I dont know how to script the function in order for me to assign it a button

```
<script>
    var player;
    var intv;
    var slider;
    //Init
    //
    ////////////////////////////
    window.onload = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('btnlast').addEventListener('click',playLast, false);
        document.getElementById('btnPlay').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
        document.getElementById('btnPause').addEventListener('click', pauseMusic, false);
        document.getElementById('btnStop').addEventListener('click', stopMusic, false);
        document.getElementById('btnVolUp').addEventListener('click', volUp, false);
        document.getElementById('btnVolDown').addEventListener('click', volDown, false);
        player = document.getElementById('player');
        slider = document.getElementById('sliderTime');
        slider.addEventListener('change', reposition, false);
    }

    function reposition()
    {
        player.currentTime = slider.value;
    }


    //Volume Controls
    //
    // 0.0  Silent - 1.0 Full Volume
    /////////////////////////////
    function volUp()
    {
        if(player.volume < 1)
        {
            player.volume += 0.1;
            console.log(player.volume);
        } else
        {
            player.volume = 1;
        }
    }

    function volDown()
    {
        if(player.volume > 0)
        {
            player.volume -= 0.1;
            console.log(player.volume);
        } else
        {
            player.volume = 0;
        }
    }
    //Music Play Controls
    //
    ///////////////////////////
    function playMusic()
    {
        player.play();
        intv = setInterval(update, 100);
        slider.max = player.duration;
    }

    function update()
    {
        document.getElementById('songTime').innerHTML = millisToMins(player.currentTime);
        slider.value = player.currentTime;
    }

    function millisToMins(seconds)
    {
        var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
        var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
        if (numseconds >= 10)
        {
            return "Time Elapsed: " + numminutes + ":" + Math.round(numseconds);
        } else
        {
            return "Time Elapsed: " + numminutes + ":0" + Math.round(numseconds);
        }
    }

    function pauseMusic()
    {
        player.pause();
        clearInterval(intv);
    }

    function stopMusic()
    {
        player.pause();
        player.currentTime = 0;
        clearInterval(intv);
    }
```

Comment: 1) Don't use the `jQuery` tag if your question does not involve jQuery. 2) Actually *use* jQuery and your code will be a lot shorter/simpler :) 3) Please show a sample of your HTML to save other having to mock it up!

Comment: sorry @TrueBlueAussie Didnt realize But I am Amateur to Jquery and Javascript